# How to add the data to Google Analytis by using java (programmatically)

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

At the current moment, I am trying to understand how to add any data to GA. I read the data from my GA account using Core Reporting API and Managment API without any problems. But now I want to add the data (the number of phone calls) to GA account programmatically. Somebody can explain me step by step - how can I do this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for information. I can't understand where I can get Client ID (cid). I saw the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid  but nothing to explain where is Client ID.  In "Credentials"  I have OAuth 2.0 client IDs - xxxxxx.....apps.googleusercontent.com   may be this is my Client ID or not?

Comment: Make one up its just a string.  Think of it as more of a session id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) is how we send data to Google Analytics.   The JavaScript snippet that we use in our websites also uses the Measurement protocol as do the SDK's for Android and IOS.  Unfortunately there is no (official) SDKs for the other languages like Java for instance.

That being said you can technically code it yourself in any language that can handle a HTTP get or a HTTP post.  I have personally done it for C#.

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

payload_data


The following parameters are required for each payload:
v=1              // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555         // Anonymous Client ID.
&t=              // Hit Type.
```

A few tips to get you started.

1. Check out [validating hits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) this is very useful in the beginning for debugging your requests.
2. some of the parameters are only valid for certain hit types. Make sure you check the documentation.
3. Cid is just a string it can be anything most people send a Guid its basically used by the server to identify a unique session.
4. if you are doing this for an application google analytics account remember to send screenview not pageview the same goes for web application.
5. check the realtime report on google analytics to see if your hits are getting recorded.

**Update for question in comment:**

I recommend while you are getting the idea of this you start with just using HTTP GET in a web browser.  Its easer to test your requests against debug that way.  For example put this in a browser.

```
https://google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=pageview&dp=%2FpageA
```

[DP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dp) is document path and I am not sure why it is requiring that you send that.

**ScreenView hit type VS PageView hit type.**

There are two types of Google Analytics accounts ones for applications like android applications or sometimes web applications, and web sites.   Application Google analytics accounts are meant to be used with ScreenView hit (the user checks a screen in the application) type and web accounts use PageViews (the user views a webpage).  If you send a Pageview to an application Google Analytics account it will accept the [hit](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#t) but there will be no way for you to see the data.  If you send a ScreenView to a web Google Analytics account it will again accept the data but you wont see it.

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation and tips! Now I am sending a simple HTTP Post:                                                                                            private String googleURL = "https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect";
    private String googleVersion = "1";
    private String googleTrackingID = "UA-....";
    private String googleClientID = "375";

Comment: and after that I get the answer from server: "valid": false,    "parserMessage": [ {      "messageType": "ERROR",      "description": "A value is required for parameter 'dp'   Can you explain what is wrong? Please, explain what does it mean tip number 4? (about pageview)

Comment: Check the update to the answer.  I hope you are enjoying the measurement protocol its tricky in the start.  Sit down and figure out exactly what you want to log and test it in a web browser.   Then code your http posts.

Comment: DalmTo thanks for the help! I understood why GA need "dp" parameter. If we use pageview or screenview we should point out "dp" for other parameters (event etc) is not necessarily.  But now I want to add a event to GA. How can I do It (How to create a valid HTTP request?). For example, I need to add "number" (integer) and "info" (string). Should I create a new field or may be I can add to the event field?

Comment: Event Hit:  https://google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=event&ec=Category&ea=Action&el=Label&ev=55   Like I said its pretty easy once you get used to building up the request and learn how to read the documentation.   I should probably do a couple of tutorials on this.

Comment: I used this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#enhancedecom   + hit-builder  and I did everything I wanted. You really helped me. thank you. The last question that I have - Can I delete events from GA?

Comment: Once data has been inserted into Google Analytics it is there for life you cant delete it unless you delete the Profile itself and then you loose all the data.  Not recommended :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation))